# How to change Liferay Flag drop down values?

Tags: liferay

In liferay message board thread if we click on "Flag" then a window pop-up is coming with drop down values like "Violent & repulsive", "Spam" etc.

I want to change these text with my own words. I found code inside `tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\ROOT\html\portlet\flags\edit_entry.jsp`:

```
<option value="<%= reason %>"><liferay-ui:message key="<%= reason %>" /></option>
```

which is displaying the drop down but how can I edit the drop-down menu with my own words?

If anyone can suggest me how to proceed for here will be great help for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way (easiest) is to override the following property in portal-ext.properties:

```
flags.reasons=sexual-content,violent-or-repulsive-content,My own flag,My content,Your violent acts
```

Hope this helps.

Extend this (to make it multilingual) by providing a new localization key instead of just a text. You can use a hook to introduce a new localization key into the portal, then just use the key here. If the key cannot be found (like in this sample e.g. "My own flag") it will be shown nontranslated.

Comment: If possible please let me know how can I customize the subject or signature of the mail to admin after marking content with "Flag".

I am following link: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/flags-portlet

Comment: according to the link you would need to create a custom template file (my_custom.tmpl) for subject or message and give the path to that in portal-ext.properties. But I suppose since these *.tmpl files are in portal-impl.jar you would require an EXT. Not sure if it would work in a plugin-portlet or hook

Comment: Thanks prakash for your response. Anyway I will check these option and post the update.